# How can I add a database in plugin Database Navigator (Intellij Idea Community)?

Tags: postgresql, intellij-idea

I already have a database in this **manager dbs**, but I have not found an opportunity to add another database to the deployed **Postgresql DBMS**.  In the **Intellij Idea Ultimate** version, the database manager can do this. I can't find such a feature in the **Database Navigator** *plugin*.

[image]

I created a schema and thought to make a new database in it. But it didn't work out. Here, each database should have its own session and its own connection (I think so).

Can someone tell me how to do it ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add another database, you should use the console for that. So, you will be able to write the query for creating this new one.

First click on your db. Once done you will write you query in the console located at the left. Follow the image to do this.

[image]

Hope this will be help you.

Comment: You use Intellij Idea Ultimate, but I use Community where there is no database manager, which you showed in the figure above. So I installed the Database navigator plugin.

Comment: Okay dear, I think you can do that by just clicking **Consoles** or the console icon on the top

Comment: I haven't found how to do it.